# How can I get windows XP product key in C#?

Tags: c#

How can I get windows XP product key in C# ?

I want to get some key like windows key from client side.

Comment: Why do you need the product key? Most uses of that seem rather nefarious...

Comment: Could be a valid application to manage corporate assets, a trojan to steal Windows product codes, digital fingerprinting (beware, thar be enforced patents in them waters)... At least some use cases are valid.

Answer (score 9):

Windows Product Key Finder and other solutions mentioned here by Erij J. and others are working for Windows XP and Windows 7 only. Microsoft has changed key encryption algorithm since Windows 8.

I've found a solution for Windows 8 and up on blogpost here:
http://winaero.com/blog/how-to-view-your-product-key-in-windows-10-windows-8-and-windows-7/

However it is written in VBS, so I've rewritten it to C#.

You can check full project on GitHub: https://github.com/mrpeardotnet/WinProdKeyFinder

Here is the code how to decode product key in Windows 8 and up:

```
    public static string DecodeProductKeyWin8AndUp(byte[] digitalProductId)
    {
        var key = String.Empty;
        const int keyOffset = 52;
        var isWin8 = (byte)((digitalProductId[66] / 6) & 1);
        digitalProductId[66] = (byte)((digitalProductId[66] & 0xf7) | (isWin8 & 2) * 4);

        // Possible alpha-numeric characters in product key.
        const string digits = "BCDFGHJKMPQRTVWXY2346789";
        int last = 0;
        for (var i = 24; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            var current = 0;
            for (var j = 14; j >= 0; j--)
            {
                current = current*256;
                current = digitalProductId[j + keyOffset] + current;
                digitalProductId[j + keyOffset] = (byte)(current/24);
                current = current%24;
                last = current;
            }
            key = digits[current] + key;
        }
        var keypart1 = key.Substring(1, last);
        const string insert = "N";
        key = key.Substring(1).Replace(keypart1, keypart1 + insert);
        if (last == 0)
            key = insert + key;
        for (var i = 5; i < key.Length; i += 6)
        {
            key = key.Insert(i, "-");
        }
        return key;
    }
```

To check Windows version and get digitalProductId use wrapper method like this:

```
    public static string GetWindowsProductKey()
    {
            var key = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine,
                                          RegistryView.Default);
            const string keyPath = @"Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion";
            var digitalProductId = (byte[])key.OpenSubKey(keyPath).GetValue("DigitalProductId");

        var isWin8OrUp =
            (Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major == 6 && System.Environment.OSVersion.Version.Minor >= 2)
            ||
            (Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major > 6);

        var productKey = isWin8OrUp ? DecodeProductKeyWin8AndUp(digitalProductId) : DecodeProductKey(digitalProductId);
        return productKey;
    }
```

I've tested it on several machines and it was giving me correct results. Even on Windows 10 I was able to get generic Windows 10 code (on upgraded system).

Note: For me the original vbs script was returning wrong Win7 keys despite the fact that original blogpost states the code works for Win7 and up. So I always fallback to the well known old method for Win7 and lower.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

Check out Windows Product Key Finder.

http://wpkf.codeplex.com/

Source is available.

The key is stored in the registry and needs to be decoded using an algorithm available in the source.

Answer (score 3):

WMI has a class, called [`Win32_OperatingSystem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394239(v=vs.85).aspx) that contains a property called **SerialNumber**:

> Operating system product serial identification number.
>
> Example: "10497-OEM-0031416-71674"

The [`System.Management`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management(v=vs.110).aspx) namespace contains classes that allow .NET code to interact with WMI.

Comment: This isn't the product key, it's a product ID that bears no resemblance to the product key.

Comment: and actually crashes in winXP. I don't know why.

Answer (score 1):

Going with **mrpeardotnet's** answer...

I was getting errors where `RegistryView.Default` would not convert to string.
I changed this:

```
var key = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Default);
```

to this:

```
var key = RegistryKey.OpenRemoteBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, Environment.MachineName);
```

and it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Using this code, you can find the product key of your Microsoft products.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Win32;
namespace MSKeyFinder
{
    public class KeyDecoder
    {
        public enum Key { XP, Office10, Office11 };
        public static byte[] GetRegistryDigitalProductId(Key key)
        {
            byte[] digitalProductId = null;
            RegistryKey registry = null;
            switch (key)
            {
                // Open the XP subkey readonly.
                case Key.XP:
                    registry =
                      Registry.LocalMachine.
                        OpenSubKey(
                          @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion",
                            false);
                    break;
                // Open the Office 10 subkey readonly.
                case Key.Office10:
                    registry =
                      Registry.LocalMachine.
                        OpenSubKey(
                          @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\10.0\Registration\" + 
                          @"{90280409-6000-11D3-8CFE-0050048383C9}",
                          false);
                    // TODO: Open the registry key.
                    break;
                // Open the Office 11 subkey readonly.
                case Key.Office11:
                    // TODO: Open the registry key.
                    break;
            }
            if (registry != null)
            {
                // TODO: For other products, key name maybe different.
                digitalProductId = registry.GetValue("DigitalProductId")
                  as byte[];
                registry.Close();
            }
            return digitalProductId;
        }
        public static string DecodeProductKey(byte[] digitalProductId)
        {
            // Offset of first byte of encoded product key in 
            //  'DigitalProductIdxxx" REG_BINARY value. Offset = 34H.
            const int keyStartIndex = 52;
            // Offset of last byte of encoded product key in 
            //  'DigitalProductIdxxx" REG_BINARY value. Offset = 43H.
            const int keyEndIndex = keyStartIndex + 15;
            // Possible alpha-numeric characters in product key.
            char[] digits = new char[]
      {
        'B', 'C', 'D', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'J', 'K', 'M', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 
        'T', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', '2', '3', '4', '6', '7', '8', '9',
      };
            // Length of decoded product key
            const int decodeLength = 29;
            // Length of decoded product key in byte-form.
            // Each byte represents 2 chars.
            const int decodeStringLength = 15;
            // Array of containing the decoded product key.
            char[] decodedChars = new char[decodeLength];
            // Extract byte 52 to 67 inclusive.
            ArrayList hexPid = new ArrayList();
            for (int i = keyStartIndex; i <= keyEndIndex; i++)
            {
                hexPid.Add(digitalProductId[i]);
            }
            for (int i = decodeLength - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                // Every sixth char is a separator.
                if ((i + 1) % 6 == 0)
                {
                    decodedChars[i] = '-';
                }
                else
                {
                    // Do the actual decoding.
                    int digitMapIndex = 0;
                    for (int j = decodeStringLength - 1; j >= 0; j--)
                    {
                        int byteValue = (digitMapIndex << 8) | (byte)hexPid[j];
                        hexPid[j] = (byte)(byteValue / 24);
                        digitMapIndex = byteValue % 24;
                        decodedChars[i] = digits[digitMapIndex];
                    }
                }
            }
            return new string(decodedChars);
        }
    }
}
```

Referenced by : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23334/Microsoft-Product-Key-Finder

Comment: If you reference an article (this is the same link as @resokk posted), please provide a citation (link to original).  Also, are you sure this works for Vista and later?  The article only references XP.