# WMI query for product id (Serial Number) returns wrong results

Tags: c#, .net, wmi-query

I wrote a WMI query like below about windows product id (Serial Number) but it doesn't return product ID.What is the reason?

```
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher =
                   new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2",
                   "SELECT * FROM Win32_OperatingSystem");

               foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get())
               {
                   Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
                   Console.WriteLine("Win32_OperatingSystem instance");
                   Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
                   Console.WriteLine("SerialNumber: {0}", queryObj["SerialNumber"]);
               }


               return Convert.ToString(searcher.ToString());
```

Comment: What does it return? An exception, a null value, the incorrect value...?

Comment: You mean you want the ABCDE-FGHIJ-KLMNO-PQRST-UVWXY product ID? Your code - or at least the Powershell equivalent I've just tested - does produce the same product ID you'll find in the System control panel menu.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get windows product key in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10926634/how-can-i-get-windows-product-key-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

can you try my code

```
        ManagementClass wmi = new ManagementClass("Win32_OperatingSystem");
        foreach (var item in wmi.GetInstances())
        {
            string serialNumber = Convert.ToString(item["SerialNumber"]);
            Console.WriteLine(serialNumber);
        }
```

Comment: Please try to explain why this code is better and what the op was doing wrong here as well.